# HttpInterceptor in Angular 4.3: Intercepting 400 error responses

Tags: angular, interceptor

I would like **to intercept 401 and other errors** in order to react accordingly. This is my interceptor:

```
import { LoggingService } from './../logging/logging.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class TwsHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private logger: LoggingService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.logger.logDebug(request);    
        return next.handle(request)
            .do(event => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    this.logger.logDebug(event);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

While this works well for 200 requests, **it does not intercept the error respsonses**

All I see in chrome's dev console is this:

> zone.js:2616 GET http://localhost:8080/backend/rest/wrongurl 404 (Not
>   Found)

Or this

> zone.js:2616 GET http://localhost:8080/backend/rest/url 401
>   (Unauthorized)

I would like my interceptor to deal with this. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Http` sends errors down the error stream of an observable so you will need to catch them with `.catch` (you can read more about this [here](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html)).

```js
return next.handle(request)
  .do(event => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      this.logger.logDebug(event);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => { 
    console.log('Caught error', err);
    return Observable.throw(err);
  });
```

Comment: Ok, but this gives me this error: [ts]
Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: Adding "return Observable.throw(err);" fixes the problem. Edit your answer and I'll accept it !

Comment: @Tim like that? sorry I didn't test it before posting :)

Comment: @Tim code formatting works in comments with the `` syntax as well

Comment: for the rxjs 6 world: return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                tap(event => console.log(event)),
                catchError(err => throwError(err)),
            );

Answer (score 13):

At the time I was trying **Angular** **7+**.

> **Unfortunately** above solutions did not serve the job well because `.do` is not directly available on `HttpHandler` as of RxJs 6 pipes notion; and converting `Observable to Promise` does not stick.

Here is clean and up-to-date approach; I `pipe` the `catchError` operator and analyze the error and finally re-throw it by using `throwError`. Here is final shape of interceptor;

```js
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // client-side error or network error

        } else {
          // TODO: Clean up following by introducing method
          if (error.status === 498) { 
            // TODO: Destroy local session; redirect to /login
          }
          if (error.status === 401) { 
            // TODO: Permission denied; show toast
          }
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

Hopefully this solution will help someone in future.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably far too late for you to use, but hopefully someone else will find it useful... This is how to rewrite the above return statement to log error responses, too:

```
return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    this.logger.logDebug(event);
  }
}, (error: any) => {
  if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.logger.logDebug(error);
  }
});
```

I'm using this same methodology to automatically send all 401 Unauthorized responses directly to our logout method (rather than checking for a 401 at each individual call to http):

```
return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    // process successful responses here
  }
}, (error: any) => {
  if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      authService.logout();
    }
  }
});
```

It works like an absolute charm. :)

Comment: What if in case of an error I want to log the error but still return an HttpResponse so the Angular client could show the error message on the UI?

Comment: If you meant "HttpErrorResponse" in your question (rather than HttpResponse), the first example in my reply shows exactly that.  Both the success responses and the error responses are logged, and then passed on as if there was no interceptor at all.

Answer (score 0):

To intercept Http response error in angular 6, I make a little trick converting Observable to Promise:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   const obs = next.handle(req);

   if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
     // Handle offline error
     this.messageService.showError('No Internet Connection');
     return;
   }

   obs.toPromise().catch((error) => {
     this.messageService.progress(false);
     this.messageService.showError(error.message);
   });
   return obs;
}
```