# Error handling in Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling

I am trying to handle my errors while im doing API calls in Angular. I get the following message when I cannot connect to my API Service and want to catch this error **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**.

I searched some examples on the internet and got to this bit of code.

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/api/chatbot/connection/"+this.token).subscribe(response => {
    res => this.conversation = res
}, 
err => {
    console.log("error");
}, 
() => {
    console.log("we're finished")
});
```

It reaches the error part, but it still returns the connection error aswell:

[image: connection refused error]

Should I handle this in a different way?

Comment: [Getting error details](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a http-interceptor to intercept all http calls in your angular application. And you can handle any http error using that interceptor.

Go through this post please.

[HttpInterceptor in Angular 4.3: Intercepting 400 error responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367321/httpinterceptor-in-angular-4-3-intercepting-400-error-responses)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using the interceptor and the catch method, but it gives the same result. It reads the error and gives back a response, but the error message like in my previous post also remains.