# How to access error response body inside of an interceptor?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I use interceptor to sniff all HTTP requests/responses.

How to get body response in case when server returns http 400, Angular raises an exception and in catch block I can not get body message:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
   catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(error.body); // There is not body object here
});
```

Comment: Choose an appropriate answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367321/httpinterceptor-in-angular-4-3-intercepting-400-error-responses. Make an attempt to do some research before posting.

Comment: There is not appropriate answer for me, it solves another problem, not getting body from error response.

Comment: Why would you expect one? The [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse) clearly indicate that there is no `body` property on the `HttpErrorResponse`.

Comment: Read https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse#description

Comment: _The error property will contain either a wrapped Error object or the error response returned from the server._

Comment: Okay, how then handle this? Or return another http code?\

Comment: Some answers already hinted at how you can typecheck the error instance and access its properties. Try something and update your question with it.

Comment: I tried, one case it is change http code from 400 to another?

Comment: I have found problem, seems it is CORS problem, that is why I can not get body response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do it with help of `Interceptor`

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
     if (error.status === 400) {
      // Do your thing here      
   }         
  }
```

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: I do this, try to get body response inside ` if (error.status === 400) {}` Angular cuts this

Comment: I have found problem, seems it is CORS problem, that is why I can not get body response

Comment: @OPV  Greattttt  

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I use `HttpErrorResponse` from `'@angular/common/http'` to achieve this
for example:

```
this.http.get('url').subscribe( response => {

 }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 404) {
             // do stuff
        }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I want to use this in interception, not in each methods

Comment: `err` is witout body response